# Background thread behind django project

Tags: python, django, multithreading, background

I never worked on web application/service side and not sure if this is the right way for my work:
I have data collection system collecting data from serial port, and also want to present the data to user using web service. I'm thinking of creating a Django project to show my data on website. Also, to collecting the data, I need some background thread running when the website started. I'm trying to re-use the models defined in my django project in the data collecting thread.

First, I'd like to know if this is a reasonable design? If yes, is there any easy way to do that? I saw a lot topics about background tasks using celery but those are very complicate scenarios. Isn't there an easy way for this?

Comment: When you say "serial port," do you mean [this kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port), on the client's computer?

Comment: I have made something similar, where I created a project and deployed it on a server, but had a stripped-down version on a different computer collecting and uploading data. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Celery is good, if you have tasks need to be runned in background. For example it could be a interaction with web-workers ( like sending emails, massive updates in stores and etc), or it could be parallel tasks, when one master worker sends tasks to celery server ( or servers ).

In you case, I think better solution is:

- Create one daemon, which will talk with your SERIAL PORT in infinite loop and save data somewhere.
- Web workers, which will read this data and represent to user.
- If will need something like, long queries with heavy calculation for users, you can add Celery to your stack, and this celery will work as web workers, just read data and return results to web workers.